# Column stacking multidemensional array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a multidimensional array

```
a = np.array([(1,2,3,4), (11,21,31,41), (3,3,3,3), (12, 24, 15, 100)])
```

I am wondering if there is a way to use numpy column stack such that  when I output it to a another file using numpy.savetxt I get what I display below?

```
1 11 3 12
2 21 3 24
3 31 3 15
4 41 3 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the array as the transpose:

```
>>> np.savetxt('dat',a.T)
>>> np.loadtxt('dat')
array([[   1.,   11.,    3.,   12.],
       [   2.,   21.,    3.,   24.],
       [   3.,   31.,    3.,   15.],
       [   4.,   41.,    3.,  100.]])
```

Or if you do not want decimals in the saved text:

```
>>> np.savetxt('dat',a.T,fmt='%.0f')

####@glados:$ head dat
1 11 3 12
2 21 3 24
3 31 3 15
4 41 3 100
```